# Creating an iPhone music Visualiser based on Fourier Transform

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, fft

I am designing a music visualiser application for the iPhone.

I was thinking of doing this by picking up data via the iPhone's mic, running a Fourier Transform on it and then creating visualisations.

The best example I have been able to get of this is [aurioTuch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html) which produces a perfect graph based on FFT data. However I have been struggling to understand / replicate aurioTouch in my own project.

I am unable to understand where exactly aurioTouch picks up the data from the microphone before it does the FFT?

Also is there any other examples of code that I could use to do this in my project? Or any other tips?

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious, but did you try to follow the program step-by-step in debug mode? What are the exact difficulties you encountered?

Comment: Yes I have followed the programme code. Might just me being thick here but I am unable to determine where exactly it gets the data from the microphone. Any insight on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I am planning myself to use the input of the mic, I thought your question is a good opportunity to get familiar with a relevant sample code.

I will trace back the steps of reading through the code:

1. Starting off in `SpectrumAnalysis.cpp` (since it is obvious the audio has to get to this class somehow), you can see that the class method `SpectrumAnalysisProcess` has a 2nd input argument `const int32_t* inTimeSig` --- sounds a promising starting point, since the input time signal is what we are looking for.
2. Using the right-click menu item `Find in project` on this method, you can see that except for the obvious definition & declaration, this method is used only inside the `FFTBufferManager::ComputeFFT` method, where it gets `mAudioBuffer` as its 2nd argument (the `inTimeSig` from step 1). Looking for this class data member gives more then 2 or 3 results, but most of them are again just definitions/memory alloc etc. The interesting search result is where `mAudioBuffer` is used as argument to `memcopy`, inside the method `FFTBufferManager::GrabAudioData`.
3. Again using the search option, we see that `FFTBufferManager::GrabAudioData` is called only once, inside a method called `PerformThru`. This method has an input argument called `ioData` (sounds promising) of type `AudioBufferList`.
4. Looking for `PerformThru`, we see it is used in the following line: `inputProc.inputProc = PerformThru;` - we're almost there:: it looks like registering a callback function. Looking for the type of `inputProc`, we indeed see it is `AURenderCallbackStruct` - that's it. The callback is called by the audio framework, who is responsible to feed it with samples.

You will probably have to read the documentation for `AURenderCallbackStruct` (or better off, the [Audio Unit Hosting](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)) to get a deeper understanding, but I hope this gave you a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Itamar. However I've run into another problem now where I cannot seem to record microphone data and play music from the iPod library simultaneously. Any insight on this?

Comment: Maybe these links will be helpful: http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/ and http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html