# Setup for Apple's Accelerate FFT for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, fft, microphone, accelerate-framework

i am trying to understand the concepts of digital sound proceesing and i want to implement the FFT of Apple's Accelerate Framework [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=Accelerate). In the vDSP API you can find a nice and fast FFT but unfortunately i can not set it up right. I think the documentation is really hard to understand. I am trying to FFT the signal of the iPhone's microphone. Can somebody give me a setup or some sites where i can read about this? Would be really great.

Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505694/creating-an-iphone-music-visualiser-based-on-fourier-transform/4513801#4513801

Comment: As Tom points out, this looks to be a duplicate of the question [Using the apple FFT and accelerate Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398753/using-the-apple-fft-and-accelerate-framework), which has some very good answers.

Comment: i saw this question but unfortunately the answers didn't help because i don't have a strong sound related background...

Comment: Perhaps it would be good then to start at a more basic level.  FFTs are a little more advanced of a concept.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i am trying to get the frequencies of the user's input.

Answer (score 0):

Does Aurio Touch use vDSP ? I didn't the last time I looked, but it might now. I think that you are after a power spectrum.

Found this:
[Audio File FFT in an OS X environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964955/audio-file-fft-in-an-os-x-environment)

Also Apple's example source would collapse down a bit if you deleted all the G4 ppc code...

The audio comes at you as integers: FFTs need floats. Convert with vDSP_vflt32 or similar.

Aurio touch is good cause you can see how all the callbacks work for sound i/o.

Comment: When looking for accelerate examples, look for OS X stuff, as iOS support just came out in 4.0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398753/using-the-apple-fft-and-accelerate-framework - especially the long comment that explains everything.